# VB.NET Need help performing a '>' operation on string

Tags: vb.net, select, dataset

I'm trying to peform the following select statement on a dataset...

```
Dim weight As Double

weight = 15

dsMain.Tables(0).Select(weight & " >= MINIMUM_WEIGHT and " & weight & " < MAXIMUM_WEIGHT", "USER_NAME ASC")
```

Both MINIMUM_WEIGHT and MAXIMUM_WEIGHT are varchars (I can't change this in the database) and my variable weight is a double. This causes the following error...

"Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.Int32."

If I convert weight to a string, I then run into the situation where 10 is considered less than 5. Any suggestions as to how I can handle this type of situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert x_WEIGHT to an appropriate numeric type. The string has to be converted to a number; converting the number to a string and then comparing will lead to lexicographical/dictionary ordering, as found out.

While I've never done this in a DataSet query (but have had to in various SQL queries), it appears that [`Convert(..)`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/05/11/how-use-convert-in-a-datatable-select.aspx) is supported. In that case, the following *may* do the trick:

```
query = weight & " >= Convert(MINIMUM_WEIGHT, 'System.Int32')" & _
        " and " & weight & " < Convert(MAXIMUM_WEIGHT, 'System.Int32')"
```

However, also see how the query can be written using LINQ (from the same link). I would recommend not using a query string (especially one without placeholders) if it is feasible to switch.

Here is another untested query (this time using C# LINQ syntax), which may or may not work:

```
var v = from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where weight => Convert.ToInt32(x["MINIMUM_WEIGHT"])
            && weight < Convert.ToInt32(x["MAXIMUM_WEIGHT"])
        order by x["USER_NAME"]
        select x;
```

YMMV. Good luck!

Comment: I tried the following... Select(weight & " >= Convert(MINIMUM_WEIGHT, 'System.Int32') and " & weight & " < Convert(MAXIMUM_WEIGHT, 'System.Int32')", "USER_NAME ASC")) but I get an error stating "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Select Expression supports CONVERT function.

This is untried but may work:

```
dsMain.Tables(0).Select(weight & " BETWEEN CONVERT(MINIMUM_WEIGHT, 'System.Int32') AND CONVERT(MAXIMUM_WEIGHT, 'System.Int32)'", "USER_NAME ASC")
```

Comment: I get an error stating... The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim query = dt.Rows.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(dr) 
             weight > CDbl(dr("MINIMUM_WEIGHT").ToString) And 
             weight < CDbl(dr("MAXIMUM_WEIGHT").ToString))
```

Where dr is a DataRow, so the column name must match.